# MongoDB Java API - whats the equivalent for db.collection.remove()?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

As explained [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/#remove-all-documents-from-a-collection), `db.bios.remove()` ***deletes all*** the documents from the `bios` collection of currently connected DB. What is the equivalent method for this functionality in [MongoDB Java API](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/)?

I did not find any methods like `DB.removeCollection(..)` or `DBCollection.removeAll()`. Please help me.

Comment: I cannot add a link only answer so here: http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#remove(com.mongodb.DBObject)

Comment: have you looked here http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#remove(com.mongodb.DBObject, com.mongodb.WriteConcern) ?

Comment: I am aware of `DBCollection.remove(DBObject)` method, but I dont know how to use it to remove all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by simply calling the [remove](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#remove%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method with an empty object.

```
yourDBCollection.remove(new BasicDBObject());
```

The equivalent Mongo shell command would be `db.bios.remove({});`

Remember that MongoDB query objects work like filters: They let anything through which doesn't explicitely violates them.